# Difference between (in/on/at) "on court", "at school", "in all countries"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Using the three prepositions (in/on/at) when their use is related to the word after them is very confusing to learners.

E.g. in these examples all the prepositions refer to a location:

> The players were on court for three hours
>   Do you feel sleepy at school or at work?
>   Originally found in all countries

Also, the three prepositions are used to refer to a time like *on the weekend*, *at 7 AM* and *in the morning*.

Is there an easy way to tell which one is correct to use? If not, can someone please lead me to where (a website) I can learn to use them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First you study prepositions chapter from any standard grammar book, and the read standard newspapers and try to find the sentences where prepositions are used and think about them that in what sense they are used. Gradually you will become habitual to using correct prepositions at correct places.